# Blazor Hybrid Lifecycle

Tags: blazor, maui, blazor-hybrid

Navigating away from a component page, then back to the component page causes the component to be re-instantiated and go through the full lifecycle events (OnInitialized,SetParameters, etc.).  Anyone else seeing this?  Anyone know why?

I've flaggged each lifecycle event and I can confirm this behavior is occurring.

Comment: And what is your question/problem?

Comment: [Speculation]: Presumably this was done because the alternative is for the Blazor Component to "hold on to" all the resources needed to be a web view, even when it is not showing. That would not be good. Especially not good if you navigated to a different page that also had a BlazorWebView. Perhaps a **work-around** is to make a "master page" that is a single-cell grid; the cell fills the page. Put two elements in that grid: the BlazorWebView, and a NavigationPage (which lies "on top of" the BlazorWebVIew). Manipulate the contents of the NavigationPage, instead of moving app to different page.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Turns this is the the "normal" behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blazor apps that prerender their content on the server call `OnInitializedAsync` twice:

- Once when the component is initially rendered statically as part of the page.
- A second time when the browser renders the component.

So, the [ASP.NET Core Razor component lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#component-initialization-oninitializedasync) document gives the solutions [Component initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#component-initialization-oninitializedasync) about the situation.